# Convert current server time to ISO 8601

Tags: php, time, format

I must convert the server current time to this format:

```
2016-03-23T05:24:25.590000
```

I think this is an ISO 8601 (even if I don't understand what are the final numbers, supposedly microseconds).

How can I do? Any help is welcome

Comment: How is the input? timestamp?

Comment: Whatever, I only need it is "now" in the current server time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final numbers are the microseconds. It is easy to output a given DateTime object `$d` in this format:

```
echo $d->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u');
```

It is not so easy, to get the **current** timestamp including microseconds, because constructing it with `now` only gets whole seconds. You could go this way and append the microseconds manually:

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') . substr((string) microtime(), 1, 7);
// 2016-03-23T14:55:25.535678
```

See doc for [`microtime()`](http://php.net/manual/function.microtime.php) and [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: I asked just because it looked a bit more complicated